# Dividing two factorials

Tags: java, algorithm

I am relatively new to Java but trying to get better of course. I can't solve a decently easy looking problem but here it is :  Write a program that calculates n!/k! (factorial), take n and k as user input, check if n>k>0 and print an error if not so.

Here is what I have so far. I know I haven't done the error part of the problem but I want to make it work for now. Computing one factorial is pretty straight forward but dividing the two seemed a challenge. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks in advance!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class nkFactorial {

    @SuppressWarnings({ "resource" })
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);   
        System.out.println("Enter n");
        int n = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter k");
        int k = input.nextInt();

        long nfactorial=1;
        long kfactorial=1;

        do {
            nfactorial *=n;
            n--;
            kfactorial *=k;
            k--;
        } while (n>k && k>1);
        System.out.println("n!/k!=" + nfactorial/kfactorial );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both your exit condition `while (n>k && k>1);` and your multiplication by n and k are wrong, since they causes you to calculate n^k/k^k.

Something like this should work :

```
int kfactorial = 1;
int nfactorial = 1;
if (n>k && k>0) {
    int i = 1;
    while (i<=k) {
        nfactorial *=i;
        kfactorial *=i;
        i++;
    }
    while (i<=n) {
        nfactorial *=i;
        i++;
    }
    System.out.println("n!/k!=" + nfactorial/kfactorial );
}
```

Of course this can be made more efficient if you remember that `n!/k!=(k+1)*(k+2)*...*n` :

```
int result = 1;
if (n>k && k>0) {
    int i = k+1;
    while (i<=n) {
        result *=i;
        i++;
    }
    System.out.println("n!/k!=" + result );
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
static int divFactorials (int n, int k) {

    int result = 1;
    for (int i = n; i > k; i--)
    {
        result *= i;
    }
    return result;
}
```

This works because if you divide `n!` by `k!`, you get this for n = 6 and k = 4:

```
6!    6 * 5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * 1     
-- == ---------------------  == 6 * 5 == 30
4!            4 * 3 * 2 * 1
```

You just cancel every factor <= k so you just have to multiply the numbers > k up to including n.

---

Also please note that when working with factorials (or really big numbers in general) you are best off using [BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) for your calculations, as BigIntegers cannot overflow like an `int` or a `long`.

Comment: VG At least somebody recognized that you don't have to calculate both factorials.